# Python script to stop Tomcat service error The specified service does not exist as an installed service

Tags: python-2.7

I am using a Python script to stop the Tomcat service.  I am getting the error:

```
error: (1060, 'GetServiceKeyName', 'The specified service does not exist as an installed service.')
```

The method to stop the service is:

```
def service_info(action, machine, service):
if action == 'stop':
    win32serviceutil.StopService(service, machine)
    print '%s stopped successfully' % service
elif action == 'start':
    win32serviceutil.StartService(service, machine)
    print '%s started successfully' % service
elif action == 'restart':
    win32serviceutil.RestartService(service, machine)
    print '%s restarted successfully' % service
elif action == 'status':
    if win32serviceutil.QueryServiceStatus(service, machine)[1] == 4:
        print "%s is running normally" % service
    else:
        print "%s is *not* running" % service
```

From my base class unittest i call the method like this:

```
from Utilities.HelperMethods import recursive_overwrite, rename_file, delete_a_file, stop_a_service, service_info
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):

    machine = 'riaz-pc'
    service_tomcat = 'Tomcat7.exe'
    action_stop = 'stop'
    action_start = 'start'        
    service_info(action_stop, machine, service_tomcat)
    service_info(action_start, machine, service_tomcat)
```

I think I am giving the correct service name of Tomcat.  In the command prompt CMD i enter tasklist and I can see Tomcat7.exe
I give Tomcat7.exe as the service name.
Why is it failing?

The full error log is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\Base\BaseTestCase.py", line 35, in setUpClass
    service_info(action_stop, machine, service_tomcat)
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore 501\Utilities\HelperMethods.py", line 134, in service_info
    win32serviceutil.StopService(service, machine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 409, in StopService
    return ControlService(serviceName, win32service.SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, machine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 318, in ControlService
    hs = SmartOpenService(hscm, serviceName, win32service.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 80, in SmartOpenService
    name = win32service.GetServiceKeyName(hscm, name)
error: (1060, 'GetServiceKeyName', 'The specified service does not exist as an installed service.')
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense the service name is wrong. Try `tomcat7` instead of `Tomcat7.exe`:

```
win32serviceutil.StopService('tomcat7', 'riaz-pc')
```